# bettrer curve fitting in python

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, scipy, curve-fitting

I want to fit my data by an equation like plogx+qx+r. I use the code below and I got this figure but I want a better fit. It may be done by constraint the P,Q,R.
[image: red line is fitting by this equation]

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
def func(x, P, Q, R):
    return (P*np.log10(x))+(Q*x)+R
ydata=np.array([0.21210878, 0.22067094, 0.18488919, 0.18643416, 0.19486116, 0.19581927, 0.19999324])
xdata=np.array([32,50,75,75,110,150,210,260])
plt.plot(xdata, ydata, '-ob', label='data')
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata)
print(popt)
plt.plot(xdata, func(xdata, *popt), 'r-',label='fit: P=%6.4f, Q=%6.4f, R=%6.4f' % tuple(popt))
```

looking for help.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the data itself is problematic (not smooth like I would expect). If you have outliars, I would suggest thinking about RANSAC fitting, which is more robust than simple minimizers. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_sample_consensus